# Referring buttons of one layout in another

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to android programming and I'm having problem with referring the button of one layout in another.
Explanation:
I have a button which does some task in a layout. The code for that task is written in the layout's respective. Java file. Now I have a button in another layout which provides same functionality as the previous one and contains same code too. So instead of writing the code again, is there any way I can refer the but to from the first layout ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: The right way might be to have a single function (with the operations), accessible for both the button's on click event.

Comment: Provide some of your codes to check further. Also need to know both layouts are Activity or Fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use a single View.OnclickListenr for both buttons

```
class MyListener implements  View.OnclickListenr{

public void onClick(View view){
  // do something here
}
}
```

Now, register this listeners to both your buttons.

Comment: You're missing the 'View' parameter ;)

Answer (score 0):

So like Nishant said, what you do is extend the `View.OnClickListener` and create your own implementation of it. Depending on what parameters you need, such as passing through a `Context` object, a repository, or something that can be injected, you may need a constructor.

```
public class MyButtonListener implements View.OnClickLister {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyButtonListener(Context content) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    Public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do your on click handling here, including checking the view types
    }

}
```

Then to implement, it's as simple as:

```
Button buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
buttonView.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonListener(getActivity()));
```